# Iphone wont display an svg image in an image tag

Tags: iphone, svg, image

I am trying to get an svg in an image format to display on an iphone by using the img tag. It's fine across all modern browsers and resizes ok in the browser when I shrink the browser size down to a mobile view.

Problem is that it doesn't display on an iphone. I have tried using the embed tag and the image did display but would not pick up the css for responsive resizing.

here's the two ways I tried.

```
<img src="img/bg1.svg" />

<embed src="img/bg1.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
```

I built and saved the image in illustrator and saved it using the svg tiny 1.1 setting that is says is  for mobile devices.

Any ideas as to why why this doesn't work? Or what is the best way to display an svg for all mobile devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use an `<iframe>` that links to the SVG file to embed the image.

Comment: The site i'm working on is all built using html5, I have an inline svg on the page also and that is ok.

Comment: I see. Edited my answer because what I wrote previously was incorrect. Can you use an `<iframe>` instead of `<embed>`?

Comment: I tried an iframe but that didn't show up on an iphone4 or android. In the end I changed what I was trying to do and used png's for the same effect.